# how to make oracle table feel changes in PostgreSQL table?

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle

I have oracle database and PostgreSQL database, I want to make specific table in oracle database feel changes in table in PostgreSQL database, how can I do it without using triggers?

I tried to solve that with triggers but it is not the best solution.

Comment: Why do you think that your solution _is not the best solution_ ?

Comment: "Better" solutions are likely to be somewhat costly.  Oracle GoldenGate, for example, is a very good technical solution to replicating data across different database engines.  It is not particularly easy to set up and administer nor is it particularly cheap.

Comment: You can also use `oracle_fdw` in PostgreSQL to view tables in Oracle. But it won't store Oracle table in PostgreSQL, you have to do it yourself. `https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw`

Comment: @JustinCave no problem with some cost, I will search for it.
Can you help me and give me a tutorial to make Oracle GoldenGate way?

Comment: Here's a blog post on it: https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/post/how-to-replicate-data-using-goldengate-postgresql